# Customize Ionic Icons - ionicons

Tags: css, sass, icons, ionic3

I have a requirement to create an icon as shown below.

[image]

I have tried as shown below.

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
   <div style="background:lightblue;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%;">
    <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

[**Plunker is here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KgfAZW?p=preview)

Q1: Is this the correct approach to create this kind of icon appearance?

Q2: How can I make it same as above image?

Q3: After that, I need to use that icon any place on any component.If I use `margins` to center the `heart` icon, hope it'll not work on any place no? In other words, I need to use it as a single unit.

Hope you'll give a feedback for this.

Comment: DIV means DIVisor, so a separator, a cell of a grid layout... you need a nice small heart, think of it as inline element. So `<span>` it.

Comment: Yes, That part I know.When I used the `span` I cannot have a bigger circle.Hope you'll edit my plunker above? @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: plunkr is not working ??

Comment: It is working no? @rashidnk

Comment: I think just add `line-height:50px; text-align: center;` to your div and it will work in all case

Comment: Hope you'll put it as an answer with the working plunker? @Duannx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.heart-icon {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="heart-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Hope it is what you want to achieve. You can use ionic icon instead of font awesome.

Comment: Cool.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

scss

```
  .heart-icon {
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    color: #FFF;
  }
```

and for HTML

```
<ion-icon class="heart-icon" name="heart" item-start></ion-icon>
```